# curl not printing result

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I've run manually the url from postman, and I've successfully connected and it printed it results.

But when I tried calling it from a method, no result is printing.

here's the curl code I used:

```
public function curlHandle($apiPath, $postArray)
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $conf = $CI->config->config;
    $curlHandle = curl_init($apiPath);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 300);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArray);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $fp = fopen('/var/www/html/logs/curl_log.txt', 'w');
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
    $result = curl_exec($curlHandle);
    print_r(curl_error($curlHandle));
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die(curl_error($curlHandle));
    } else {
         $data = json_decode($result, TRUE);
    }
    curl_close($curlHandle);
    return $data;

}
```

Here's the content of curl_log.txt

> - Hostname localhost/codeignitertest was found in DNS cache
> - Trying 127.0.0.1...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - Connected to alocalhost/codeignitertest (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
>
>   > POST /test/process HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost/codeignitertest User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux
>   >     x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57
>   >     Safari/537.36 Accept: */* Content-Length: 142 Content-Type:
>   >     multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------78a116d61ad4939d
>
> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Date: Tue, 30 Apr 2019 21:19:43 GMT < Server:
>   Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) < Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache,
>   must-revalidate < Pragma: no-cache < Set-Cookie:
>   ci_session=ag85kv438n0ukb1rvrkb5cdfkrd8s2q6; expires=Tue, 30-Apr-2019
>   21:49:43 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; HttpOnly < Expires: Thu, 19 Nov
>   1981 08:52:00 GMT < Content-Length: 14 < Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8 < 
>   * Connection #0 to host localhost/codeignitertest left intact

also note that curlHandle() is from another project and localhost/codeignitertest but both are running in my localhost

Comment: You've issued the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option and have subsequently *returned* the result. This code *shouldn't* print anything.

Comment: perfect! it works, can you post your answer so I can upvote it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've issued this option:

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Which means that curl returns the output from the remote server instead of printing it.

You then capture that output into a variable:

```
$result = curl_exec($curlHandle);
```

Which you then encode and return to your caller:

```
return $data;
```

This code *shouldn't* print the results. It *returns* the results.